# CSS display:table content height

Tags: css, css-tables

I am trying to make a number of columns the same height, and have decided to go down the `display:table` CSS route.

```
<div class="header" style="display: table; width: 100%; background-color: yellow">
  <div class="title" style="font-size: 30px; display: table-cell;">Navigation Title</div>
  <div class="navigation" style="display: table-cell;">
    <a class="navigation-link" style="background-color: red">Home</a>
    <a class="navigation-link">About</a>
    <a class="navigation-link">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the `navigation-link`s to the the full height of the `header` table (so as to add `background-color` to them), but the `navigation` seems to have some padding automatically added to the top and bottom. How would i set the height of `navigation`, and `navigation-link`s to be the height of the `header` table.

I have tried using `height:100%` in various places but that did not seem to work (I am probably missing something). Here is a diagram to show what i mean:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "the full height"? Probably just make them bigger as you have done with the title.

Comment: I mean the `navigation` div to be the same height as the `header` div

Comment: To what end? It sounds like you have a hidden agenda (nothing in the question that explains why), which is the worst possible way to seek a solution. Just tell us the real problem.

Comment: I eventually wanted the `navigation-link`s to be the height of he `header` so i could add `background-color` to the individual links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to play with `display: inline-block;`, `vertical-align: top;`, `padding-top` and `height` of your navigation links:

```
.navigation {
    ...
    vertical-align: top;
}
.navigation-link {
    ...
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 7px 5px;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y8AF5/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve your problem :   [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9AhL2/)

**CSS**

```
.navigation > a {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    line-height:2.5em;

}
```

What you have done so far is styling the `class`es but no styling was done for `a` tag.

Now, the trick is to change the display type of `a` and using `line-height` to provide appropriate spacing of full height!!!